# Получение цвета слова COM MS Word

Tags: c++, qt, activex

Пытаюсь получить нормально цвет слова из документа, на что мне в ответ невообразимые цифры, как мне из них получить нормальные значения в HEX или хотя бы RGB?

Код:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAxObject>

#define _ qDebug() <<

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QAxObject *m_word = new QAxObject("Word.Application", 0);
    m_word->setProperty("Visible", true);
    QAxObject *documents = m_word->querySubObject("Documents");
    QAxObject *newDocument = documents->querySubObject("Add(QVariant)", QVariant("D:\\test.docx"));

    QAxObject *words = newDocument->querySubObject("Words");
    int countWord = words->property("Count").toInt();

    for (int a = 1; a <= countWord; a++){
        QAxObject *word = words->querySubObject("Item(int)", a)->querySubObject("FormattedText");
        QAxObject *font = word->querySubObject("Font");

        _ word->property("Text");
        _ font->property("Name");
        _ font->property("Size");
        _ font->property("Bold");
        _ font->property("Italic");
        _ font->property("Underline");
        _ font->property("StrikeThrough");
        _ font->property("Color");
        _ font->property("UnderlineColor");
        _ word->property("HighlightColorIndex");

        delete font;
        delete word;
        break;
    }

    m_word->dynamicCall("Quit()");

    delete words;
    delete newDocument;
    delete documents;
    delete m_word;

    return 0;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Ответ:

```
QVariant(QString, "Классический ")
QVariant(QString, "Times New Roman")
QVariant(double, 14)
QVariant(int, -1)
QVariant(int, 0)
QVariant(int, 1)
QVariant(int, 0)
QVariant(int, 16750848)
QVariant(int, 16711680)
QVariant(int, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем вас не устраивают эти цифры? 16750848 - это FF9900, 16711680 - это FF0000. Не вижу здесь проблемы. Вы можете перевести их в QColor примерно так:

```
quint32 c = 16711860;
QColor color(c >> 16, (c >> 8) & 0xFF, c & 0xFF, 0xFF);
```

Comment: Эти устраивают, но были минусовые значения, что меня очень напрягло.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко, отрицательные значения вполне могут быть. Если взять 32-разрядное целое число, и посмотреть, как оно устроено, то можно увидеть, что его старший бит - бит знака. Если он равен единице, то число отрицательное. Таким образом, число 0xFFFFFFFF - это минус единица. В случае с цветом, у вас, скорее всего, задействуется альфа-канал.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим на примере одного числа, которое соответствует свойству `Color`:

```
16750848
```

В шестнадцатеричной системе счисления (для перевода можете использовать обычный виндовый калькулятора) это будет выглядеть так:

```
FF9900
```

Далее не составляет труда разбить это число на байты `FF`, `99`, `00`. Если порядок этих байтов соответствует RGB, то получите следующие значения:

```
R = 255
G = 153
B = 0
```

Или в виде цвета:

> [image: цвет]

Для перевода в тип `QColor` должно быть достаточно использовать соответствующий конструктор:

```
QColor::QColor(QRgb color);
```

Т.е.

```
QColor(16750848);
```